# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string (Responsive Google Maps WP Plugin - Metabox.php on line 115)

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7, meta-boxes

Hello fellow developers and problem-solvers,

I'm running into a PHP7 issue it seems where my code needs to be updated for:

`/home/wp-theme/public_html/wp-content/plugins/responsive-google-maps/classes/MarkAdCoreClasses/Metabox.php on line 115`

I did some searches and wasn't able to find this particular issue with other threads on Stack Overflow. I'm somewhat familiar with PHP, but not a guru at working with core PHP files. I'm more of a front-end/full-stack developer.

> Error Shown on the sidebar: "Responsive Google Maps" WordPress Plugin

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /home/wp-theme/public_html/wp-content/plugins/responsive-google-maps/classes/MarkAdCoreClasses/Metabox.php:115 Stack trace: #0 /home/wp-theme/public_html/wp-admin/includes/template.php(1048): ResponsiveGoogleMaps_MarkAdCoreClasses_Metabox->render_metabox_content(Object(WP_Post), Array) #1 /home/wp-theme/public_html/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php(696): do_meta_boxes(Object(WP_Screen), 'side', Object(WP_Post)) #2 /home/wp-theme/public_html/wp-admin/post.php(173): include('/home/wp-theme...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/wp-theme/public_html/wp-content/plugins/responsive-google-maps/classes/MarkAdCoreClasses/Metabox.php on line 115`

> Source code: Metabox.php on line 115

```
$field_output .= $this->form_fields->$field['type'](array($field, $settings['metabox_id'], $passed_values));
```

Much appreciated if someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it, I was right about it being [related to PHP7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51274068/2165370).

Change

`$field_output .= $this->form_fields->$field['type'](array($field, $settings['metabox_id'], $passed_values));`

to

`$field_output .= $this->form_fields->{$field['type']}(array($field, $settings['metabox_id'], $passed_values));`

Answer (score 0):

Line 115 seems to be calling a dynamic function, whose name is retrieved from the $field variable of type array within the form_fields object.

The same issue does seem to be reported on the CodeCanyon item page a few years ago [here](https://codecanyon.net/item/responsive-google-maps/5802273/comments?page=14).

I would recommend redownloading the plugin and uploading it to /wp-content/plugins/ folder on the website to see if the latest update resolves the issue.